# About operator overloading in C++

Tags: c++, methods, operator-overloading

I have a question about operators, let's say that I have a class myclass and that i have overloaded its operator *=, [], and +

Can I access them inside the member functions with this->*=, this->[], *this + * this... ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can access them in multiple ways. You could, for example, do this:

```
*this + something
```

Or alternatively:

```
this->operator+(something)
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is just a pointer. You can do all of the following with any pointer.

This is the preferred way as it does not loose operational syntax:

```
(*this)[2]
(*this)(foo, bar)
*this / 3
*this * (that - 3) + 5
```

Its just dereferencing the pointer.

You can also use their names:

```
this->operator[](2)
this->operator() (foo, bar)
this->operator/ (3)
this->operator*(that - 3) + 5
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a special synthax for pointers, it looks like that:

`this->oprator[](0)`

`this->operator+(*this)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using external operators, it should works like that : `this->operator[](args)`